# Android Moto Droid Camera Hangs EVERY Time onTakePicture

Tags: android, camera

All, I've googled over and over again to find a solution and while I found a bug regarding camera release, etc I can not for the life of me seem to get the cam code to work.  Every time I executed takePicture the system simply hangs, sometimes it calls the `PictureCallback`, but most of the time it simply hangs.

Weird issues about not being able to read /data/ap_gain.bin files, etc

**Below is the code:**

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements Camera.PictureCallback, RequestConstants {

 private static final String TAG = "Camera";

 private Preview preview;

 private boolean previewRunning;

 private int addressNotificationId;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  addressNotificationId = getIntent().getIntExtra(REQ_RA_ID, 0);

  getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

  if (preview == null) {
   preview = new Preview(this);
  }
  setContentView(preview);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  if (isFinishing()) {
   preview.cleanup();
  }

  super.onDestroy();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA) {

   /*
   preview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   Bitmap ss = preview.getDrawingCache();
   byte[] data = ImageUtility.getImageData(ss,75,1);
   Log.v(TAG, "Pic with size: " + data.length);

   ApplicationManager.getInstance().createPacketRecord(PacketConstants.PT_FLAG_ADDRESS_PHOTO, ApplicationDatabaseManager.getInstance().getRouteAddressBySystemId(addressNotificationId), data);
   finish();
   */
   preview.getCamera().takePicture(new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onShutter() {

    }
   }, null, this);
   return true;
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

 @Override
 public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  /*
  if (data == null || isFinishing())
   return;

  camera.stopPreview();
  previewRunning = false;
  camera.release();
  */
  //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
  //data = null;
  //data = ImageUtility.getImageData(bitmap, 75,1);

  Log.v(TAG, "Pic with size: " + data.length);


  ApplicationManager.getInstance().createPacketRecord(PacketConstants.PT_FLAG_ADDRESS_PHOTO, ApplicationDatabaseManager.getInstance().getRouteAddressBySystemId(addressNotificationId), data);
  finish();
 }

}

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();

        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    Camera getCamera() {
     return mCamera;
    }

    void cleanup() {
     mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCamera == null)
         mCamera = Camera.open();

        try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
        parameters.setPictureSize(w, h);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with a Nexus One.  I hear the shutter sound, and then nothing.   In the debug log, I see "AudoHardware pcm playback is going to standby".   Any progress for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are sometimes taking a picture and sometimes not, because you are releasing the camera before the callback has occurred.

When the callback does fire, depending on whether the camera has released or not it will or will not be able to access the taken photo.

I suggest making sure that you are not releasing the camera or closing the form when you take a photo.

Better yet, close the form from the photo callback.

Also, when a photo is taken, the default action of android is to stop the Preview. this is not a bug, but the expected nature.

Answer (score 0):

After you JpegPictureCallback is called, you need to call mCamera.startPreview again.

There isn't enough info in the API Camera sample to really write a camera app, but you can get the source code for Google's own camera app here.   Camera.java contains a lot of important, useful code:

git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Camera.git